# Get current service replicas via Docker API

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get the current replica status of a service in the swarm. 
So far I only found

```
  "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 10
                }
```

in the `/services GET` which is the desired amount of replicas but not current.
Is there a place in the API that provides this info like in:

```
# docker service ls
ID                  NAME                                     MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                                  PORTS
klp0m5vt2h4s        image1   replicated          10/10               registry.xy.com/image1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve your problem somehow? Im looking for the same feature...

Comment: I ended up just cutting the field from `docker service ls` , but there might be a simpler way in a more recent version?

Answer (score 3):

you can call `/tasks` using the `service=name` and `desired-state=running` filters to get all running replicas

Comment: this shows the ones that desire to be running, but not that they are running already.

Answer (score 0):

`GET` on `/services` will list all services. You should be able to do a `GET` on `/services/id` to inspect the service and get more detailed information about it.